# Filter IObservable<string> with regex and return matched value

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a `IObservable<string>` that I want to transform into an `IObservable<int>` through a regex, that I can assign to a property through the `ToProperty` helper.

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public MyViewModel {
       var o = Observable.Create( .... );

       o.Something(s => .... )  
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Value, out _Value);    
    }

    private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<int> _value;
    public int Value { get { return _value.value; } }
}
```

**First question**
What would be the best substitute for `Something(s => ...)` ?
I guess I could use `Select(s => s.TryMatchRegex('regex'))` where `TryMatchRegex` returns a `int?` and then use `Where(i => i.HasValue)` and then a new `Select(i => i.Value)` but I don't find that very clever...

**Second question**
Now, imagine that I have several regexes. Each published value can match zero or more of these regexes. Each regex has it's corresponding property. To I need to subscribe to the source multiple times, or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be over-thinking it. Everything you've suggested sounds reasonable and would result in easy to follow code in the first instance. You can wrap the regex projection+filtering logic into a custom operator with a meaningful name to maximise readability.

*Check if performance is a problem before you optimize.* Obvious optimizations (if you need them) include:

- ***If*** you don't need to know about consecutive duplicate inputs, apply `DistinctUntilChanged().Publish().RefCount()` on `o` and subscribe your regex projections to that
- [Memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the regex application, with an appropriate caching strategy
- [Compile the regexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.compiletoassembly(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Good advice (+1), though I'm not sure the question was related to performance. To me, it seemed like the whole thing was really just about answering **Second question**, so that's what I did. SO should have a way to combine answers into one. :-)

Comment: My interpretation was that OP wanted the separate properties, so I didn't consider the `SelectMany` approach - useful to have as an option though for sure. `ToProperty` + `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` is basically a shortcut to presenting a stream as a property - very similar to `BehaviorSubject<T>` semantics. I went in to performance observations basically because I didn't have much else to add and ugliness and perf concerns are often conflated in my experience! :)

Comment: Even though performance isn't a big issue, repeating my self is one of the things I wanted to avoid in the second part. But the main issue is to express something meaningful AND in the 'native' dialect of rx. I'm quite new to reactive ways of thinking, and even though I can make my self understood in foreign lands, I try to avoid sounding like a complete dork ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A `SelectMany` query is probably best since you can use an inner `IEnumerable<T>` to represent zero or more matches.

Alternatively, you could `Publish` the source to make it `hot` so that you could write separate queries for each property without having to worry about duplicating subscription side effects, though unless you're planning on introducing concurrency yourself to execute them in parallel, the regexs are going to be applied serially anyway; therefore, it's probably best to just group them together within a single projection.

And I'd probably just use `BehaviorSubject<T>` defined natively in Rx. I'm not exactly sure what `ToProperty` offers.

For example *(untested)*:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public int X
  {
    get { return x.Value; }
    private set { x.OnNext(value); }
  }

  public int Y
  {
    get { return y.Value; }
    private set { y.OnNext(value); }
  }

  public int Z
  {
    get { return z.Value; }
    private set { z.OnNext(value); }
  }

  private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> x = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
  private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> y = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
  private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> z = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);

  public MyViewModel(IObservable<string> source)
  {
    var patterns = new Dictionary<string, IObserver<int>>()
    {
      { patternX, x },
      { patternY, y },
      { patternZ, z }
    };

    (from input in source
     from action in from pattern in patterns
                    let match = Regex.Match(input, pattern.Key)
                    where match.Success
                    let value = GetInt32Somehow(match.Value)
                    select new Action(() => pattern.Value.OnNext(value))
     select action)
     .Subscribe(action => action());
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `BehaviorSubject` which was new to me. Not sure if it'll push `ToProperty` off the table, but it's good to know about it anyway :-)